# margins and flex-wrap in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with `flex-wrap` property of a flexbox.

Here is my code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to let some space `margin` between items but without wrapping them. I want them horizontally two by two and every item with width of 50% margin included to prevent `flex-wrap`.

Comment: so remove the wrap ?

Answer (score 4):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 34%; /* fg, fs, fb */
  margin: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the `flex` shorthand, there's no need for `flex-basis` (`width`) to be 50%, which results in one item per row due to the margins.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap.

In this case, with `flex-basis: 34%`, there's plenty of space for the margins, but not enough space for a third item on each line.

Comment: And here is an answer that actual uses flexbox itself to solve the problem ;), love the way we can use the `flex-grow:1` along with `flex-basis`, saved me already some "trouble"

Comment: I would probably add more detail about the min value and the max value of the flex-basis we can use ... in this case we should choose something between `calc(100%/3 - 20px)` and `calc(50% - 20px)`

Answer (score 2):

You may use `calc` to exclude margin from the width:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 5px 10px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `calc` for this, so for example you can set `flex-basis: calc(50% - margin x 2)`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```